# Find limit inferior and limit superior of $[1+\sin n]$ and $n - [\sqrt n]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to find the *limit inferior* and *limit superior* of the following sequences: $$[1+\sin n]$$ and $$n - [\sqrt n].$$

I have done similar exercises before, but never with the integer part function (i.e., $[ \cdot ]$), and therefore I'm confused. How should I go about solving these two problems?

Comment: Just saying, it is generally considered bad form to ask two unrelated questions in one. Also, is $n$ only an integer going to infinity, or is it smoothly going to infinity (i.e. along the real line)?

Comment: @Soke They are quite related actually. $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: As in, one is not a direct follow up the other. It's just two questions asking the same thing for different examples.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**: What values can the sequence $s_n = [1 + \sin n]$ take? Note that since $n$ is an integer, $\sin n$ can never be exactly equal to $-1$ or $1$.

**Hint 2**: $n - [\sqrt{n}] \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you, but I already knew that much; what I'm missing are the formal details. Could you help me out with these?